# Como aplicar um efeito de Loading antes do carregamento da página?

Tags: javascript, eventos

Existe alguma forma de usar o JavaScript/jQuery pra medir o carregamento de uma página e exibir uma imagem .GIF até a mesma ser carregada?

Vejo exemplos, como [Preloader CSS3](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/html-css/CSS3-Loading-Animation/index.html), que usam apenas CSS3, o que me faz pensar que o carregamento é feito de uma forma "falsa", vendo que CSS3 não tem capacidade de verificar se a página foi carregada ou não (até onde meu conhecimento de CSS3 vai), mas de qualquer forma, o tutorial é muito incompleto e pelo visto não funciona em IE.

Lembrando que não é interessante para mim exibir a página até a mesma ser carregada. E seria de meu interesse que isso se aplique a todas as páginas. Vendo que o tempo de espera é real, não vejo o porque de mostrar a página sendo carregada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se a sua página está precisando de uma barra de progresso, talvez seja possível reduzir os arquivos mais pesados ou otimizar processos custosos.

De fato, não é possível usar CSS para nada do tipo, apenas exibir animações de duração fixa. Mesmo com JavaScript e HTML, não é possível calcular o volume exato de dados que já foram carregados do total. Na verdade, isso nem seria necessário, já que a própria barra de progresso do navegador cumpre este papel.

Se a a página for pesada por causa da quantidade de imagens, dá para simular algo semelhante com [Progress.js](http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/progress.htm) (página em inglês). Este script exibe uma barra de progresso, calculado com base nas imagens que já foram carregadas.

Talvez dê para adaptar o script para exibir progresso em uma imagem, como um GIF, mas a princípio é uma caixa de texto (customizável) com o valor em porcentagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outra forma de determinar o progresso seria colocar trechos de JavaScript em diferentes partes da página, que incrementem uma variável global. Por exemplo:

```
porcentagem += 10; atualizarProgresso();
```

Mas este método é ainda mais impreciso que o anterior, já que o código seria disparado assim que os arquivos fossem abertos pelo navegador, não tendo necessariamente seu conteúdo carregado por completo.

Independente da barra de progresso, é possível ocultar a página durante o carregamento utilizando uma máscara, como [jquery-loadmask](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/) (página em inglês):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>Fonte: [pergunta do Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958624/get-the-percentage-of-the-page-load-using-javascript)</sub>